# How to make Notepad++ use proxy with username and password?

Tags: proxy, notepad++, updates

This has been a frustration for a while - I am trying to figure out how to configure Notepad++ (now at v5.6.8 Unicode) to use a proxy server with a specific username and password when connecting to check for updates. At the moment I get a dialog stating:

```
curl error
couldn't connect to host
```

When setting up the **Plugin Manager** I have given it the proxy server address in the form: `username:password@server-address` and supplied the port in the separate box - which works (although somewhat uncomfortable as this exposes my username/password).

How can I achieve the equivalent with the main update configuration? I've searched extensively on both the Notepad++ wiki and Google with no success other than a possible reference to using a local proxy to force connections to gateway properly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Notepad++ uses Generic Updater for win32 (it's free).

The updater is located here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\updater`
Assuming you've used default installation path and running 64-bit windows and notepad++ 32-bit. If not look try here as well: `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\updater\`

What you need to do is start command line (e.g. Start->run->cmd OR Start->(search programs and files)->command) as administrator and execute the following lines:

```
1. cd /d C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\updater
2. gup -options
```

This will bring up proxy settings dialog where you can enter your proxy address.

Comment: Thank you! How did you work this one out?

Comment: Should be mentioned that the proxy settings of Notepad+ have to be empty to make this work.

Comment: I'm on the latest version (7.9.5) and I don't have the option of setting the credentials, just the url and port. None of the answers actually cover the specific "with username and password" part of the question.

Answer (score 12):

Notepad++ has added `Set Updater proxy...` command to the `?` menu for setting the proxy of updater since `v6.3.1`.

Please refer to [NotePad++ v6.3.1 Change Log](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the update - makes this much simpler when you can get it through the client!

Comment: There is no such option in v6.6.8

Comment: I can still find this option in v6.6.8.

Answer (score 10):

After I completed the steps bellow, I was able to update the Plugin Manager and install new plugins like XML Tools:

1. Go to Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager

   [image]
2. Click on Settings.

   [image]
3. Fill in the Proxy address and port - with your data

   [image]

Comment: The OP wrote that Plugin Manager Updates work fine.

Answer (score 6):

Since it appears to be using curl, I tried [setting](https://superuser.com/a/284351/48078) the `http_proxy` environment variable and that seemed to work as well. I set it to something like

`http://username:password@proxy.domain.com:port/`

Might be more compatible, central, and obvious than Generic Updater's internal config.

Note, curl also uses `https_proxy` and `ftp_proxy` environment variables. Doesn't appear to be needed for current versions of notepad++, but if you're setting one, you may want to set the others for future proofing (HTTPS is probably more important than FTP).

Comment: Thanks for providing another option - guess it just depends what you're doing and how!

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. And I didn't even need username and password, just domain and port.