# What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?

Tags: path, environment-variables, community-faq

Questions about

- setting environment variables
- the `PATH`

are very common here, and in most cases the answers are very similar to each other. In the future it would be nice to have a good Q/A for this.

So the question is: **What are environment variables, like the executable `PATH`, and how can I change and use them on major operating systems?**

A good answer would include a simple explanation of what environment variables and especially `PATH` mean to the OS, as well as simple guidelines on how to set and read them accordingly.

Comment: Tired of having to do it manually each time I needed to, I wrote some registry entries to add context menu entries for AddToPath and RemoveFromPath to folders, utilizing a free app called pathed.exe . Following is the link to the complete guide: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/add-remove-any-folder-to-path-variable-using-context-menu/ I can now very easily add folders to PATH variable or remove them from it, without having to edit any file or worry about messing up the formatting of the variable. Hope it helps. =)

Comment: On Windows there is a shortcut for opening properties of System ie. Control Panel -> System
It's WIN key on keyboard + Pause/Break (WIN+Break). This is extremely helpful and speeding up process of setting new environmental variables on Win8 because there you have to click through several windows in modern ui (Yeah. If it's modern then I'll grow a cactus on my palm) which is just annoying. Of course you can create powershell script or use setx command and don't worry any more about it :D

Comment: In Windows 8, the fastest navigation to changing system and user environment variables is using search. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> brings up the search for all settings. Search for `env` and the needed options are listed.

Comment: I think it's faster and clearer by opening `CMD` and typing `set`, or `PowerShell` and typing `Get-Childitem env:`.

Comment: If you're editing the path variable a lot (like when setting up a new system), it might help to have a shortcut to the System Properties dialog on the desktop. To do so, right click on the desktop, select New Shortcut, and enter systempropertiesadvanced.exe. Then you can click on the link to get to the System Properties dialog, then click on Environment Variables to get to the dialog with the path settings.

Comment: Great post about it: http://www.windows-commandline.com/set-path-command-line/

Answer (score 395):

## What are Environment Variables?

Environment variables hold values related to the current environment, like the Operating System or user sessions.

### Path

One of the most well-known is called `PATH` on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. It specifies the directories in which executable programs* are located on the machine that can be started without knowing and typing the whole path to the file on the command line. (Or in Windows, the *Run* dialog in the Start Menu or <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

On Linux and Mac OS X, it usually holds all `bin` and `sbin` directories relevant for the current user. On Windows, it contains at least the `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\system32` directories — that's why you can *run* `calc.exe` or `notepad.exe` from the command line or *Run* dialog, but not `firefox.exe`. (Firefox is located in `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox`. For information on how to include Firefox, go [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140205002800/http://www.overclock.net/t/15588/how-can-i-start-applications-easily-with-the-run-dialog-box).)

For example, typing `calc` (the `.exe` *can* be omitted) in the command line on Windows will start up the Windows Calculator.

* You can add support for file extensions other than `.exe` by editing [`%PATHEXT%`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1785).

### Other

Other variables might tell programs what kind of terminal is used (`TERM` on Linux/Mac OS X), or, on Windows, where the Windows folder is located (e.g., `%WINDIR%` is `C:\Windows`).

### Creating new environment variables

In Windows, Linux and Unix, it's possible to create new environment variables, whose values are then made available to all programs upon launch.

You can use this when writing scripts or programs that are installed or deployed to multiple machines and need to reference values that are specific to these machines. While a similar effect can be achieved using program-specific configuration settings, it's easier to do this using an environment variable if multiple programs need to access the same value.

## Windows

### GUI

1. Open `Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables`.
2. Type `control sysdm.cpl,,3` in the Run dialog (<kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and click `Environment Variables`.
   For editing user variables you can also type

   ```
   %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
   ```

   in the Run dialog.
3. Right-click (My) Computer and click on Properties, or simply press <kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.

   - In XP click on `Advanced » Environment Variables`.
   - In Vista+ click on `Advanced system settings » Environment Variables`.
4. There are many other ways of reaching the same place, such as by typing "environment variables" in the Start Menu/Screen search box and so on.

Environment variables in Windows are separated into user and machine/system specific values. You can view and edit their values there. Their current values upon launch are made available to all programs.

There is also [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about), which helps setting and changing environment variables in Windows without the need to go deep into the system settings. Another open source program for Windows with which the path environment can be edited very conveniently is [Path Editor](http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor/).

### Command Line

#### Format

Environment Variables in Windows are denoted with percent signs (%) surrounding the name:

```
%name%
```

#### echo

To display an environment variable's value in `cmd.exe`, type `echo %name%`.

```
C:\>echo %USERPROFILE%
C:\Users\Daniel
```

#### set

To **create/set** a variable, use `set varname=value`:

```
C:\>set FunnyCatPictures=C:\Users\Daniel\Pictures\Funny Cat Pictures

C:\>set FunnyCatPicturesTwo=%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Funny Cat Pictures 2
```

To **append/add** a variable, use `set varname=value;%varname%`:

```
C:\>set Penguins=C:\Linux

C:\>set Penguins=C:\Windows;%Penguins%

C:\>echo %Penguins%
C:\Windows;C:\Linux
```

Environment variables set in this way are available for (the rest of)
the duration of the Command Prompt process in which they are set,
and are available to processes that are started after the variables were set.

#### setx

To **create/set** a variable **permanently**, use `setx varname "value"`:

```
C:\>setx FunnyCatPictures "C:\Users\Daniel\Pictures\Funny Cat Pictures"

[Restart CMD]

C:\>echo %FunnyCatPictures%
C:\Users\Daniel\Pictures\Funny Cat Pictures
```

Unlike `set`, there is no equals sign and the value should be enclosed in quotes if it contains any spaces.  Note that variables may expand to a string with spaces (e.g., `%PATH%` becomes `C:\Program Files`), so it is best to include quotes around values that contain any variables.

You must manually add `setx` to versions of Windows earlier than Vista.
[Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en)

### List of Windows Environment Variables

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values) is a list of **default environment variables**, which are built into Windows. Some examples are:
`%WINDIR%`, `%SystemRoot%`, `%USERPROFILE%`, and `%APPDATA%`.
Like most names in Windows, these are case-insensitive.

## Unix derivatives (FreeBSD, GNU / Linux, OS X)

Environment Variables in Linux are prefixed with a dollar sign ($) such as $HOME or $HOSTNAME. Many well-known and standard variables are spelled out in capital letters to signify just that. Keep in mind that variable names are case-sensitive, meaning that $User and $USER are entirely unrelated from the shell's point of view.

Unix derivatives define system wide variables in shell scripts located mostly in the `/etc` folder, but user-specific values may be given to those variables in scripts located in the home folder (e.g., `/etc/profile`, `$HOME/.bash_profile`). The `.profile` file in the home folder is a common place to define user variables.

**Setting variables**

These files are regular shell scripts and can contain more than just environment variable declarations. To set an environment variable, use `export`. To show your currently defined environment variables in a terminal, run `env`.

The `export` command is a standard way to define variables. The syntax is very intuitive. The outcome is identical for these two lines, but the first alternative is preferable in case portability to pre-POSIX Bourne shell is necessary.

```
var=value; export var
export var=value
```

The C shell and its descendants use a completely different syntax; there, the command is `setenv`.

See the Linux documentation project, [Path HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Path.html) for a more thorough discussion on this topic.

Perhaps contrary to common belief, OS X is more "Unix" than Linux. Additionally to the files already mentioned, $PATH can be modified in these files:

- `/etc/paths` contains all default directories that are added to the path, like `/bin` and `/usr/sbin`.
- Any file in `/etc/paths.d` — commonly used by installers to make the executable files they provide available from the shell without touching system-wide or user-specific configuration files. These files simply contain one path per line. e.g., /Programs/Mozilla/Calendar/bin.

### External Links:

> [Environment Variables in XP](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm)
>   [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en) (Includes `setx`)
>   [Environment Variables in Windows Vista and Windows 7](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment-variables-windows-vista-7.htm)
>   [Adding executables to the Run Dialog Box](https://web.archive.org/web/20140205002800/http://www.overclock.net/t/15588/how-can-i-start-applications-easily-with-the-run-dialog-box)
>   [Mac OSX Tips - Setting Environment Variables](http://mactip.blogspot.com/2004/04/setting-environment-variables.html)
>   [TLDP: Path Howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Path.html)

Comment: On Windows Vista onwards you can use `SETX` to make permanent changes.    It has a slightly different syntax.  `SETX` has to be added from the `Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit` for earlier versions of `NT`.

Comment: @paradroid Nice, didn't know that (not a Windows user). This topic is community wiki, you can go ahead and just edit in that information.

Comment: What you describe as "Shell" are not environment variables.  Nor do they apply solely to Windows Explorer.  That is an environment variable _template_, which any program that understands the protocol can participate in using.  See [this ServerFault answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/240570/windows-environment-variables-and-manual-registry-editing-no-wrong-values-issue/241012#241012).

Comment: @JdeBP I don't understand how this applies here, as the user mentioned it didn't work with editing the registry, but *did* work when editing using the dialog. What's your point?

Comment: The point is fairly clearly made.  Here it is in boldface: **These are not environment variables, merely a _template_ from which environment variables _are constructed_, and they are _not_ confined solely to Microsoft Windows Explorer (the "shell").**

Comment: @JdeBP The section title was meant to reference *how to set these values on the user interface*, which is called *shell* on Windows, in contrast to the section following, *command-line interface*. I edited this before I even saw your comment 10 hours ago. Noone ever mentioned that this applied only to Explorer.

Comment: @JdeBP The answer you linked to doesn't really apply in this case, since you talked about setting the values in the registry. Setting via dialog will broadcast that `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` I imagine, and therefore notify interested parties about the new values. That's why I asked how it applied here. Making something boldface doesn't change its meaning and neither makes it easier to understand, just like repeating the same sentence, only louder. Also, I edited this post a few hours ago to specifically mention that the values the processes receive are set when they are launched.

Comment: @JdeBP You might also notice that the question is rather basic in nature. Carefully explaining the intricacies of how changes to the environment variables are distributed (seriously, `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`? Windows API? This isn't this question's audience!) might not be a good idea, as it might confuse the reader instead of explaining what these variables are about.

Comment: @muntoo Thanks for working on this answer. I have to ask though about the wording *It specifies the directories in which executable programs are located on the machine. Programs that are located in the directories specified by PATH can be started without knowing and typing the whole path to the file on the command line.* — any reason you changed it like you did (aside from grammar issues)? Programs can be located pretty much anywhere, the path only is used for locating; so I disagree with how the first sentence turned out.

Comment: @Daniel I was trying to 'chop' it into shorter sentences (what every English teacher seems to advocate), but I accidentally introduced that mistake. (Fixed, now.) I've also added a suggested 'For example' which might make it easier to understand. It's a bit redundant, though. Maybe you can help integrate it into the post a bit better?

Comment: I'd say it's a very elaborate answer that will surely help many people, thanks to all who helped to write it. I don't think we should go into Windows' internals either, that's not what I intended with the question anyway.

Comment: I don't think either `Rapid Environment Editor` or `Path Editor` are open source. [RapidEE license](http://www.rapidee.com/en/license), no license for `Path Editor`. Perhaps you were thinking of [PathEd](http://pathed.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: @Daniel What do you mean by "note that if %PATH% is included, there *will* be spaces"?

Comment: @Pacerier This answer was collaboratively edited, and that section not written by me. That said I just checked and it seems `%PATH%` by default contains entries referring to folders in `C:\Program files`, meaning that it evaluates to a string with spaces that needs proper quoting.

Comment: @DanielBeck, Ok, I've edited it.

Comment: @Pacerier I don't think that's right. There is no sane configuration where `PATH` *equals* `C:\Program files`.

Comment: @DanielBeck, Why not? I'm not experiencing any problems.

Comment: Quotes are needed when the argument for Windows `set` command contains spaces. Both following commands will work, the first will make the variable contain the quotes: `set FunnyCatPictures="C:\Users\Daniel\Pictures\Funny Cat Pictures"` and the second not: `set "FunnyCatPictures=C:\Users\Daniel\Pictures\Funny Cat Pictures"`

Comment: @tripleee I'm not convinced that your edit is correct. "export VAR=value" works for me in `dash`, and [the POSIX man page for export](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/export) shows the syntax as `export name[=word]`. Can you provide a reference supporting your claim?

Comment: @G-Man [I can now](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193095/where-is-export-var-value-not-available) -- thanks for asking (-:  Edit suggestion submitted.

Answer (score 80):

This post is from a more technical point of view than Daniel's, but doesn't explain as much the concepts.

---

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) is also an excellent referrence.

#### Linux and most BSDs

In most command-line shells, temporary environment variables are set using `export` (sh, bash, zsh) or `setenv` (csh, tcsh) commands.

- Examples for prepending `$HOME/bin` to `$PATH` in bash or zsh:

  ```
  export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
  ```

  (In this particular case, `export` is unnecessary since `PATH` is already part of the environment.)
- csh, tcsh:

  ```
  setenv PATH "$HOME/bin:$PATH"
  ```

Persistent environment variables can be set during several separate stages:

- Login:

  - Login session setup: Linux `pam_env`, which usually reads from `/etc/environment`
  - Terminal logins: The shell's "profile" files.

    - `bash` uses `/etc/profile` and the first one of: `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`. Manual page `bash(1)` section *Invocation*.

      Often, the user's profile file includes an explicit call for `~/.bashrc` too.
    - `zsh`: Manual page `zsh(1)` section *Startup/shutdown files*.
    - `csh` and other shells: See apropriate manual pages.
  - Graphical logins: Not sure; may vary depending on login manager. GDM appears to read `~/.profile` in my system.
- Opening of a terminal window:

  - `bash` uses `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

#### Windows NT series

- In Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`), use `set name=value` to change environment variables for that window.

  To append `c:\bin` to `%PATH%`, use:

  ```
  set path=%path%;c:\bin
  ```

  This only affects that `cmd.exe` process, and any *new* processes launched from it.
- To make persistent changes, use *Control Panel → System → Advanced → Environment Variables*. ([docs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/environment_variables.mspx?mfr=true))

  *Note:* While user settings normally override system ones, `PATH` variable is handled specially: both system and user settings are merged into the final value.

  Changes are stored to Registry (see below), and apply instantly to all *new* processes created by Explorer (the graphical shell), for example, through Start Menu.
- System-wide environment variables are kept in the Registry, `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`, and loaded at system boot.

  User environment is kept in `HKCU\Environment` and loaded during user logon.
- By default, the system also looks for `set` commands in `AUTOEXEC.NT` file.

#### MS-DOS, 16-bit Windows, Windows 9x series

- In MS-DOS Prompt (`command.com`), use `set name=value`, as in WinNT.

  Similarly, running `set` interactively only affects that one `command.com` instance, along with any new processes launched from it.
- To make persistent changes, add or edit apropriate `set` lines in `C:\AUTOEXEC.BAT`, then reboot.

  - Workaround to avoid restarting, for Windows 9x: open a MS-DOS Prompt window, set the apropriate variables, close existing Explorer process (*Start → Shut Down* → while holding Ctrl+Shift, click *Cancel*), run `explorer.exe` from the MS-DOS Prompt window.

#### VMS

<sup>(Couldn't resist.)</sup>

DCL has no concept of "path", but various symbol and command definitions can be put in `SYS$LOGIN:LOGIN.COM`.

Comment: The VMS section is wrong.  DCL has `DCL$PATH` for "[automatic foreign commands](http://h71000.www7.hp.com./doc/731final/6489/6489pro_033.html#map_nosymb)".

Answer (score 12):

**Q:** **WHAT are Environment Variables ?**

**A:** Environment Variables are similar to variables in any programming language.  In the case of Windows or Unix systems they are storing various values to allow for programs and tasks to get necessary OS information or 'Environment' information. For example:

USERPROFILE : users directory within the OS files.

MAIL : where a user's mail can be found within the OS files.

**Q: WHAT is the PATH variable specifically?**

**A:** The PATH variable sets directory paths to look in when commands are executed, both for  RUN commands, and for internal calls from programs. This prevents a program from needing to know its install location to call other executable processes.

It looks to the Windows Environment System PATH variable and tests each location for the given executable. Thus adding a location to the PATH variable allows an executable to be called directly.

According to this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)):

> When a command is entered in a command shell or a system call is made by a program to execute a program, the system first searches the current working directory and then searches the path, examining each directory from left to right

---

**Q: HOW to add a location to the PATH variable ?**

**A:** You need to edit the variable string of the Environment Variables PATH variable to include your executable's location.

One way to do this is described [here](https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500):

1. Open the Start Menu and right click on Computer. Select Properties.
2. Select Advanced system settings.
3. In the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables.
4. Select EDIT or NEW. (for PATH you most likely want to EDIT).
5. Add your location path. e.g.: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;`

I hope this clarifies some of the confusion.

Answer (score 10):

For the `bash` shell `PATH` global (non-terminal) environment variables, I follow the convention used in my Ubuntu VM installation - other shells will vary:

Caveat:  The whole shell start-up sequence, which `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc. files are sourced in which order?, when do I have to re-login to get visibility to newly defined variables, aliases, etc?,  what's the difference between a login, interactive, and non-interactive shell - I do use `cron`?, and why when I do a `. ~/.bashrc` is my stupid `PATH` variable growing longer and longer? are the key questions that come to mind when I'm thinking of my `PATH` variable.

*In fact, I just completely re-wrote my entire bash startup file set taking ideas from the Ubuntu and cygwin skeleton files, and here are some of my in sites:*

1. Export the `PATH` and other global environment variables (i.e. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) variables in the `.profile`;
2. Use logic in `~/.profile` to source `$HOME/.bashrc` if it exists;
3. Fence execution of the `~/.bashrc` with a test for interactive execution, exit otherwise;
4. Put all the aliases, `shopt`'s, prompt setup, history control, terminal setup, function definition, etc. (interactive related setup) in the part of `~/.bashrc` that is protected to only run in interactive mode;
5. Get rid of the other bash startup files, because their existence determines whether the control path through `.profile` and `.bashrc` works as expected.  That is, unless there are specific requirements to do otherwise, remove `~/.bash_profile` & `~/.bash_login`;
6. When I'm at the bash prompt, and I need to update some default setup, I edit my `~/.bashrc` file, then simply source it with a `. ~/.bashrc` to get those changes in my current shell.
7. When I make a change to an environment variable like `PATH`, I need to modify and source my `~/.profile`;
8. I put my calls to fink, port, and brew specific setups in `.profile`.

*That's my 2 cents on this topic.*

Comment: I can only say that this is an excellent way of keeping everything tidy :) While the answer is old-ish, it nevertheless remains relevant; `bash` is not going away that soon (even if Apple already ditched it!), while the "login sequence" will remain confusing (at best) and contra-intuitive for decades to come, so long as computers continue to be built using a Von Neumann architecture...

Answer (score 5):

## Windows 10, without admin account

Control Panel -> User Accounts -> User Accounts -> Change my environment variables

Note you have to **click on the header "User Accounts"**:
[image: Note you have to click on the header "User Accounts"]

Again, you have to **click on the header "User Accounts"**:
[image: Note again you have to click on the header "User Accounts"]

[image: Change my environment variables]

[image: Environment Variables]

Comment: Thanks!  can you show Windows 8.1?

Comment: @Chris22 I only have Win10 in my work laptop, but I'd assume in Windows 8 it would be either similar to Win10 or Win7.

Comment: thanks.  I'll try it.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer.